# Check if all elements in array are the same value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array 'sub_status_arr' which contains a set of values.

If all elements in that array are 52, a button is displayed, else something else is displayed.

I tried the following but it does not seem to work properly. It is only checking if the array contains 51 and ignoring the rest

```
<%if sub_status_arr.include? 51 || 53 || 54 %>
  display button
<% else %>
  do something else
<% end %>
```

How do I check if all elements in the array are 52?

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try the `all?` function:

```
if sub_status_arr.all? {|ss| ss == 52}
```

Comment: I would probably also use `all?` but, this is much faster: `sub_status_arr.count(52) == sub_starus_arr.size`

Comment: @LeeJarvis That's a neat trick! Wouldn't have thought of trying that. I wonder where the speed increase comes from... it would probably be negligible as the size of the array grows to infinity.

Comment: Yeah I haven't tried it on super large arrays. But I guess the size of the array is stored so it doesn't need to traverse every object in the array and use `==`which could get expensive. I guess you could also do `sub_status_arr.uniq == [52]` as well